# How do I call the "writing voice" which is on the google android keyboard?

Tags: android

The new Google Android keyboard, comes with a button to activate the "writing voice."

How do I enable "writing with voice" of the new Google Android keyboard with just a click of the button (without having to create a new window for "writing voice", just use what exists in the Google Android keyboard)?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't.  If you want to do voice input, use the TextToSpeech api.  There's no way to even be sure the Google default keyboard is available (some devs such as Samsung replace the keyboard with their own).  Otherwise let the user activate his default keyboard's voice input if he wishes.